# Can't connect to a docker container using its IP address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj

I am using docker-compose to start up some containers which form a cluster of Solr and Zookeeper nodes.

This is my compose file (taken from [here](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml)):

```yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  solr1:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8981:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr2:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "8982:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr3:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    container_name: solr3
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 7001:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr

  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zoo2
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo2
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
      - 7002:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr

  zoo3:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zoo3
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo3
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
      - 7003:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr

networks:
  solr:
```

If I run `docker compose ls`, I see that the project is correctly running:

```
NAME                STATUS
solr-cluster        running(6)
```

and this is the output of `docker container ls`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                NAMES
d5333378e78c   25b74ae1e488   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp, :::8983->8983/tcp                                                                            solr3
5fac27cd0443   25b74ae1e488   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   0.0.0.0:8982->8983/tcp, :::8982->8983/tcp                                                                            solr2
db37ef90ca98   25b74ae1e488   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   0.0.0.0:8981->8983/tcp, :::8981->8983/tcp                                                                            solr1
b8b55694e281   a72350516291   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2183->2181/tcp, :::2183->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7003->7000/tcp, :::7003->7000/tcp   zoo3
10885eafe4e8   a72350516291   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2182->2181/tcp, :::2182->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7002->7000/tcp, :::7002->7000/tcp   zoo2
558f8574c036   a72350516291   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 hours ago   Up 52 minutes   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7001->7000/tcp, :::7001->7000/tcp   zoo1
```

If I try to navigate a solr node with my browser using host `localhost` (e.g. `http://localhost:8983/`), the container responds correctly with the Solr Admin interface.

However, if I try to access with my browser the same container but from its IP (e.g. `http://172.23.0.7:8983/`, where `172.23.0.7` is the IP of `solr3` container) I get a connection timeout. I also get a connection timeout if I try to ping that IP.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't both `localhost` and `172.23.0.7` hosts work?

I need to access my container from its IP because the Solr nodes registers to Zookeeper using their IP. So, since I can't access the containers from their IP, I get a ConnectionTimeout exception when I try to connect to them programmatically through the SolrJ APIs:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> zkNodes = new ArrayList<>(3);

    zkNodes.add("localhost:2181");
    zkNodes.add("localhost:2182");
    zkNodes.add("localhost:2183");

    SolrClient solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkNodes, Optional.empty())
        .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
        .withSocketTimeout(10000)
        .build();

    try
    {
        CollectionAdminRequest.listCollections(solrClient);
    }
    catch (IOException | SolrServerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: http://172.23.0.7:8983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.doRequest(LBSolrClient.java:370)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.request(LBSolrClient.java:298)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.sendRequest(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:1157)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:918)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.request(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:231)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CollectionAdminRequest.listCollections(CollectionAdminRequest.java:2690)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.23.0.7:8983 [/172.23.0.7] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.23.0.7:8983 [/172.23.0.7] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:571)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 21 more
```

I don't know if it that may help, but anyway I am on a Windows host, so I cannot use the `--network host` flag for Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `172.x.x.x` IPs are IPs only reachable within the Docker network, that is between the Solr and Zookeeper nodes.

When you connect to Zookeeper from outside, Zookeeper doesn't know there is an "outside", it only knows IP of Solr servers in its network and send them back to you. But these IPs are not reachable from "outside".

One workaround can be to connect to Solr servers directly instead of using Zookeeper (with URLs like `localhost:8981` and `HttpSolrClient`).

Or, you need to tell Solr servers to "present" themselves with the outside IP to Zookeeper.

Comment: So I was wrong when I thought that both `localhost` and `172.23.0.7` should work. I have googled and I've found out that through the [`SOLR_HOST`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/taking-solr-to-production.html#solr-hostname) environemt variable Solr can register to Zookeeper using an hostname which is reachable from the outside. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Even though [Gaël J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68489957/9864539) solves the problem in the general case, I'll post an answer to explain what needs to be done for Solr.

First, you need to tell Solr what is its hostname, by using the [`SOLR_HOST`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/taking-solr-to-production.html#solr-hostname) environment variable. This is the hostname Solr uses when it registers itself to Zookeeper and it's also the hostname that Zookeeper sends to its clients when they ask for a Solr URL.

In my case, such clients were:

1. a SolrJ application which run on the Docker host machine (but outside from Docker);
2. the other Solr nodes, which may ask to Zookeeper the URL of other nodes

To make the `SOLR_HOST` understandable by both of these clients, I used the value of `services.solrX.container_name` as the `SOLR_HOST`, and I have added that value also to my `hosts` file on the Docker host machine.

So, this is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yml
services:
  solr1:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8981:8981"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181
      - SOLR_HOST=solr1
      - SOLR_PORT=8981
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  solr2:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "8982:8982"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181
      - SOLR_HOST=solr2
      - SOLR_PORT=8982
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 7001:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr

networks:
  solr:
```

and this is the `hosts` file:

```
# local solr cloud cluster
127.0.0.1       solr1 solr2
```

Note also that both `solr1` and `solr2` point to `localhost`, so they should have different ports (this is why the `SOLR_PORT` environment variable is needed; otherwise both nodes would use the default `8983` port).

Answer (score 0):

I think the advertised address for solar instances are the IP's of docker instances and the ports are the default ones instead of the redirected ones. You should register the docker ports instead of the solr ports in the pods.

Maybe the solrcloud part of the solr.xml can help, but not sure...

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/format-of-solr-xml.html